# Azure App Service on Linux plan encoding issue

Tags: node.js, linux, azure

I deployed a node app "typically prerender server" to two different places and tested prerender with a get request to a url contains Arabic letters

**1. Heruko**: working perfectly

**2. Azure App Service on linux plan** failed with HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.

here is the respond body from Postsman

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bad Request</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
        <style type="text/css">.cf-hidden { display: none; } .cf-invisible { visibility: hidden; }</style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Bad Request - Invalid URL</h2>
        <hr>
        <p>HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Notice that the response head/meta contains charset=us-ascii

here is how the prerender node app see part of the url

```
u008aÙ\u0088Ù\u0085_Ù\u0085Ù\u0083Ø±Ù\u0088Ù\u0086Ø¹
```

i even created a node docker image to set language and locale to en_US.UTF-8 and changed Azure App to use this Docker image but still get error.

Any help please ?!

Comment: I also created [prerender server](https://github.com/prerender/prerender) on Azure App Service on Linux (http://aaronnodeonlinux.azurewebsites.net). Could you provide more details for how to produce this issue?

Comment: Thanks for your efforts,please try to prerender this link http://journas.com/Darwish_Post/post/48432/ما-لا-تعرفه-عن-عيد-العمال-

Comment: When you call your deployed server with the link I gave above http://aaronnodeonlinux.azurewebsites.net/http://journas.com/Darwish_Post/post/48432/ما-لا-تعرفه-عن-عيد-العمال-  it will give you bad request...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, after some investigation, I still don't understand why this issue occurred.

Actually **App Service on Linux** are still in Preview and not in Production yet. In this case, I would suggest you use an alternative offering, like Cloud Service or VM instead.

I have also tried to create prerender server on an **Azure Linux Virtual Machine** (Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS), and it worked well.

Comment: could you tell me why the response header says **Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0**

Comment: i created ubuntu virtual machine, i hope that issue will be resolved in the release version of App Service on Linux